# How to skip rows from table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, subquery, distinct

I have one table which has the following data, I want to skip row 3,  just want to fetch OPEN status only once, I am using below query but it skipping wor 5 as well.

```
    SELECT t.*
FROM emailEvent t
  JOIN 
    ( SELECT MIN(id) AS minid
      FROM emailEvent WHERE email_id = 3
      GROUP BY status
    ) AS grp
    ON grp.minid = t.id
WHERE (t.email_id = 3)
```

I came up with this as a solution but not sure if there are any other best solution for this

```
 SELECT t.*
FROM emailEvent t
WHERE t.status != "Open" and t.email_id = 3
UNION
(
SELECT et.*
FROM emailEvent et
WHERE et.status = "Open" and et.email_id = 3
ORDER BY et.createdAt DESC LIMIT 1
)
```

[image]

I want the result to be look like something like this
[image]

Comment: Where does orgid come from. Its not in your sample tables.

Comment: Include everything but that id t.id != 3 ?

Comment: @TomC that was typo

Comment: Does your version of MySQL support ROW_NUMBER?

Comment: yes it does support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM
 (
   SELECT t.*, 
      min(id) over (partition by status) as min_id
   FROM emailEvent t
   WHERE (t.email_id = 3)   -- only email 3
 ) AS dt
WHERE id = min_id           -- only for 'Open' status
   OR status <> 'Open'
```

For older releases not supporting *Windowed Aggregates*:

```
select * 
from emailEvent
where email_id = 3
and 
  (
   e.status <> 'Open'
   or id in (select min(id)  -- only for 'Open' status
          from emailEvent 
          where status = 'Open'
          and email_id = 3)
  )
```

Comment: What is `partition by status` means here?

Comment: It's similar to GROUP BY for aggregates, it calculates the min(id) for each status

Answer (score 1):

With `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select e.* from emailEvent e
where e.status <> 'Open'
or not exists (select 1 from emailEvent where status = e.status and id < e.id)
```